# Postgres Docker error: invalid record length at 0/15CF478: wanted 24, got 0

Tags: postgresql, docker, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Problem with Postgres 13
When I move all data from my old macbook m1 to macbook m3 pro
I get error invalid record length at 0/15CF478: wanted 24, got 0
I run it in docker compose

Mu docker compose

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
    database:
        image: postgis/postgis:13-3.4
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
        ports:
            - ${DB_PORT}:5432
        volumes:
            - test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
```

Logs from container

```
2024-02-05 18:40:36 The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
2024-02-05 18:40:36 This user must also own the server process.
2024-02-05 18:40:36 
2024-02-05 18:40:36 The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
2024-02-05 18:40:36 The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
2024-02-05 18:40:36 The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2024-02-05 18:40:36 
2024-02-05 18:40:36 Data page checksums are disabled.
2024-02-05 18:40:36 
2024-02-05 18:40:36 fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
2024-02-05 18:40:36 creating subdirectories ... ok
2024-02-05 18:40:36 selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
2024-02-05 18:40:37 selecting default max_connections ... 100
2024-02-05 18:40:37 selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
2024-02-05 18:40:37 selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
2024-02-05 18:40:37 creating configuration files ... ok
2024-02-05 18:40:37 running bootstrap script ... ok
2024-02-05 18:40:39 performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
2024-02-05 18:40:39 syncing data to disk ... ok
2024-02-05 18:40:39 
2024-02-05 18:40:39 
2024-02-05 18:40:39 Success. You can now start the database server using:
2024-02-05 18:40:39 
2024-02-05 18:40:39     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
2024-02-05 18:40:39 
2024-02-05 18:40:39 waiting for server to start....2024-02-05 18:40:39.393 EET [122] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.13 (Debian 13.13-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2024-02-05 18:40:39 2024-02-05 18:40:39.396 EET [122] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-02-05 18:40:39 2024-02-05 18:40:39.410 EET [126] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-05 18:40:39 EET
2024-02-05 18:40:39 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:40:39 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:40:39 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:40:39 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:40:39 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:40:39 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:40:39  stopped waiting
2024-02-05 18:43:03 
2024-02-05 18:43:03 PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2024-02-05 18:43:03 
2024-02-05 18:40:39 initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
2024-02-05 18:40:39 You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
2024-02-05 18:40:39 --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
2024-02-05 18:40:39 pg_ctl: could not start server
2024-02-05 18:40:39 Examine the log output.
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.259 EET [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.13 (Debian 13.13-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.262 EET [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.262 EET [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.264 EET [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.279 EET [63] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2024-02-05 18:40:39 EET
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.319 EET [63] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.322 EET [63] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/15CF478: wanted 24, got 0
2024-02-05 18:43:03 2024-02-05 18:43:03.322 EET [63] LOG:  redo is not required
2024-02-05 18:43:03 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:43:03 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:43:03 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:43:03 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:43:03 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
2024-02-05 18:43:03 qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
```

I try to use pg_resetwal, remove image, remove docker, change postgres images

Comment: Define *...move all data...*? At a guess you tried to move the contents of $PGDATA, possibly from a running instance.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I mean, that I bought new mac and move all data from old to new device with migration assistant.
Maybe problem in m3 pro processor

Comment: The problem is most likely due to what migration assistant did, I am presuming a direct  copy of the on disk files. For the reasons stated here [File system level backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-file.html) the chances of that working are slim to none. Your best option is to a [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) of the m1 Postgres instance then a `psql ... -f the_dumpall_file.sql` to the m3 instance. Read the `pg_dumpall` link for more information.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think this is not exactly what I need, I don’t need the data, I don’t mind if all the data is deleted

Comment: Then get rid of the reference to the old data directory(`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) and let Postgres init a new data cluster from scratch. Currently you are getting *PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization* and the server is trying to start against the $PGDATA(`/var/lib/postgresql/data`) that was pulled over by the migration. That data directory is in an incomplete state which is leading to the error.

Comment: Got to thinking, you don't need to get rid of `/var/lib/postgresql/data` just remove all the file under it. The the Postgres `initdb` would see an empty directory and proceed with initializing a new cluster.